# Azure Data Factory - if with multiple conditions

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I want to create a pipeline in ADF checking if the data has the correct format. I want to check the number of columns, file size, etc. If any of these conditions are not met I want to send an email. It is my pipeline

[image: Pipeline layout]

I wrote the first condition in my pipeline and everything worked correctly.

```
@not(equals(activity('Get Metadata1').output.size,0))
```

However when I wanted to add the next condition. So my whole condition looks like this.

```
@not(equals(activity('Get Metadata1').output.size,0)) and equals(activity('Get Metadata1').output.columnCount,5)
```

I started getting this error message.

> 'not' is a primitive and doesn't support nested properties

Could you let me know how I can approach this?

Answer (score 5):

The [and] operator should be a function call as follows...

```
@and(not(equals(activity('Get Metadata1').output.size,0)),equals(activity('Get Metadata1').output.columnCount,5))
```

With 3 conditions...

```
@and(and(not(equals(activity('Get Metadata1').output.size,0)),equals(activity('Get Metadata1').output.columnCount,5)),equals(activity('Get Metadata1').output.exists,true))
```

With 4 conditions...

```
@and(and(and(not(equals(activity('Get Metadata1').output.size,0)),equals(activity('Get Metadata1').output.columnCount,5)),equals(activity('Get Metadata1').output.exists,true)),equals(1,1))
```

See the documentation for the syntax for Expression Functions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions).

Comment: Thank you, could you give me an eqample how you woul write this? It would be great if it could for my case.

Comment: Replaced the entire answer.  The prior info was based on a different set of expression functions.  Sorry for any confusion.  The explicit answer above provides what you need.

Comment: Thank you it has worked. Do you know what I should do when I want to add more then two conditions? I can add multiple and, but I am wandering if there is any better solution

Comment: Please see the edits above to show examples of using more conditions.  I added a link to the documentation too, which should help for any future needs.  As this information has answered your question and request for elaboration, please mark this response as the answer so that others may see your question has a solution which may help them as well.

Comment: Hi, I want to implement if condition expression inside if condition activity like if(A=='s') or if(B=='q') then i have to get true or false. please help me how do we do in expression ways with activity output